# Customize JSON output in Django Rest Framework GET call

Tags: python, json, django, django-rest-framework

I'm attempting to retrieve a filtered list from a MySQL database. The query itself looks fine, but the JSON returned shows this:

```json
[
  {
    "id": "0038",
    "name": "Jane Doe",
    "total_hrs_per_week": 6,
    "timezone": "America/Los_Angeles"
  },
  {
    "id": "0039",
    "name": "John Doe",
    "total_hrs_per_week": 10,
    "timezone": "America/Los_Angeles"
  }
]
```

when the spec that I need to build to wants this:

```json
{
  "people": [
    {
      "id": "0038",
      "name": "Jane Doe",
      "total_hrs_per_week": 6,
      "timezone": "America/Los_Angeles"
    },
    {
      "id": "0039",
      "name": "John Doe",
      "total_hrs_per_week": 10,
      "timezone": "America/Los_Angeles"
    }
  ]
}
```

Here's my serializer

```
class PeopleListSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    id = serializers.CharField(source='id')
    name =serializers.CharField(source='name')
    total_hrs_per_week = serializers.IntegerField(source='total_hrs_per_week')
    timezone = serializers.CharField(source='timezone')

    class Meta:
        model = models.Person
        fields = ('id','name','total_hrs_per_week','timezone')
```

Any idea how to wrap the returned results in this way?

EDIT:

I tried wrapping this in another serializer like so

```
    class PeopleListWrapperSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
        people = PeopleListSerializer(many=True)
         
        class Meta:
            fields = ['people']
```

But this throws the following error:

> Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `people` on serializer `PeopleListWrapperSerializer`.
> The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `Person` instance.
> Original exception text was: 'Person' object has no attribute 'people'.

Comment: Try without fields = ['people'], it will take that field anyway. Maybe it gets confused there. But it's only a guess.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do that by overriding the `list()` method.

```
class PeopleListView(ListAPIView):

    def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        # call the original 'list' to get the original response
        response = super(PeopleListView, self).list(request, *args, **kwargs) 

        # customize the response data
        response.data = {"people": response.data} 

        # return response with this custom representation
        return response
```

Comment: This works, however do you know of a solution that keeps any/all of that code within the serializer classes? I'd rather not control serialization from the view.

Comment: @L.W. I am currently not aware of a method to do this using just the serializers. Will update my answer upon knowing any 
such method.

Comment: Accepting this as the answer. Couldn't find any other solution either.

Comment: Just as an additional resource, it might help to look into pagination classes (which actually do a similar thing to that in the solution above). https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/pagination/

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how you'll want incoming data and your models, you can:

- use [nested serializers](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#writable-nested-serializers)
- Customize the [renderers](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/renderers/#custom-renderers) and the [parser](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/parsers/#custom-parsers)
- Override the [default view methods](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#mixins) and wrap the serializer's result in your own expected output

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but here's an alternative solution that modifies the ***serializer*** instead of the ***view***.

The trick is to customize the `ListSerializer`, [as described in the DRF documentation](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#customizing-listserializer-behavior).

Basically, you define a custom `ListSerializer`...

```py
class MyListSerializer(serializers.ListSerializer):
    def to_representation(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return {'people': super().to_representation(*args, **kwargs)}
```

... and configure your `ModelSerializer` to use it:

```py
class PeopleListSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    ...
    class Meta:
        ...
        list_serializer_class = MyListSerializer
```

Also see [overriding serialization and deserialization behavior](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#overriding-serialization-and-deserialization-behavior).